# GLSL Shader won't work on mac

Tags: java, macos, opengl, glsl

I am trying to create a GLSL texture shader in java on a mac, but mac doesn't support any version above #version 120. How would I port this 330 shader:

```
//this is my Vertex Shader
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 texCoord;

out vec2 texCoord0;

uniform mat4 transform;

void main()
{
    gl_Position=transform*vec4(position,1.0);
    texCoord0=texCoord;
}
```

This is my Fragment Shader

```
#version 330

in vec2 texCoord0;

uniform sampler2D sampler;

out vec4 gl_FragColor;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor=texture2D(sampler,texCoord0.xy);

}
```

How do I convert these shaders to glsl 120 without losing functionality?

Comment: `in` -> `attribute`, `out` -> `varying`.  Drop the `layout` qualifiers.  Drop the `gl_FragColor` declaration.

Comment: Mac OSX does support OpenGL 3.3, you just need to make sure you're creating the context correctly.

Comment: Note that Mac doesn't support the compatibility profile for 3.1+, which is why attempts to get a higher context versions may have failed.

Comment: @Iggy modern OS X (Mavericks and Yosemite) do, but possibly not older versions.

Comment: `texture2D` is deprecated and not present in a core profile shader. This shader *might* work on other platforms because the compiler will fallback to a compatibility profile (usually with a warning or two), but it's not going to work on OS X until you replace that function with `texture`. Also remove the declaration of `gl_FragColor`, you're not allowed to re-declare that GLSL built-in.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to:

_Remove the `layout` qualifiers (including location assignment). You'll the have to use

```
void glBindAttribLocation(GLuint program,
                           GLuint index,
                           const GLchar *name);
```

for each input of your vertex shader (with **index** set to 0 and 1 for location 0 and 1 and the **name** of the variable in case you didn't understand) before  linking your program

_In the **vertex shader**, replace `in` by `attribute` and `out` by `varying`

_In the **fragment shader**, replace `in` by `varying` and use `gl_FragColor` but without declaring it

In your case, you would have this just before linking your program:

```
//program is your shader program of course...
//Bind vertex shader attributes (ins) instead of using layout
glBindAttribLocation(program, 0, "position");
glBindAttribLocation(program, 1, "texCoord");

//Then the program should be linked (or relinked, it doesn't matter)
glLinkProgram(program);
```

Your vertex shader:

```
#version 120

attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec2 texCoord;

varying vec2 texCoord0;

uniform mat4 transform;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = transform*vec4(position, 1.0);
    texCoord0 = texCoord;
}
```

And your fragment shader:

```
#version 120

varying vec2 texCoord0;

uniform sampler2D sampler;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(sampler, texCoord0.xy);

}
```

Comment: Could you write out what this would look like (ie. What exactly to plug into the glBindAttribLocation function and how it would look)? This was requestested by a user in an edit who could not yet comment.